# excel vba compare cells

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried and tested so many ways, but was never able to get what I needed.

I have a Excel sheet containing this data: (This is a summary, I have more then 150 000 lines)

```
A          B      C

30170   38,08    553299
30170   -12      553299
30170   -0,8     553299
30172   38,08    553299
30172   -12      553299
30172   -0,8     553299
30173   19,04    553299
30173   -6       553299
30173   -0,4     553299
30174   19,04    553299
30174   -6       553299
30174   -0,4     553299
90221   197,29   553299
90221   -5,92    553299
```

What I need to do:

1. test every cells in column A and column C
2. select(Row) that has a match
3. delete the last row of the match
4. loop to the end of the excel sheet.

To be more precise, I would need to calculate each row in column B and compare with the last row of the selection.

**example:** the first three lines are the same, take first two rows sum it then * by 3% and if the last row equal, delete the last row.

Not sure if I'm clear enough, if you need more info let me know.

Comment: WTF did I just read? Your question is very vague. Could you clean it up?

Comment: WTF indeed. This makes no sense, whatsoever.  Also: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Thanks guys for the WTF!!! Not always easy to put what we have in mind to words...

I will try to be clear enough...

column A is Item code, column B is Price, Column C is invoice number.

I need to match item code with item code and invoice number with invoice number.(Line 1 to 3 is a match) and (Line 4 to 6 is a match) etc...

After a match is found I need to take Price column(B), add the first lines together(not the last) this will give me a result then I multiply this result by 3% if the formula result equal the last line(third line or whatever the last line is) delete the line...

Answer (score 0):

This might work and skips loops (equals much faster execution)

```
Sub Sample()

    Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-3]&RC[-1] = R[1]C[-3]&R[1]C[-1],"""",IF(ABS(CEILING(SUMIFS(R[-1]C2:R2C2,R[-1]C1:R2C1,RC1,R[-1]C3:R2C3,RC3)*0.03,0.1))=ABS(RC[-2]),""Delete"",""""))"
    Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D15"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("D").Delete
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

***Warning:*** Also test code on a **COPY** of your data until you are 100% sure it is correct

***NOTE:*** This answer assumes you have headers on your data if you do not a few more lines will need to be added for full functionality.